# OpenSSL command line tool version and cipher

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have 2 computers - lets name it **A** and **B**. Both have the same OpenSSL version installed. Both Debian 8.3.

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
```

I try to connect to a mailserver via SSL from both.

```
openssl s_client -host pop.amailserver.net -port 995
```

From **A** I need to specify the ssl-version (parameter -tls1 or -tls1_1) to make it work.

If not I get an error.

```
SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:wrong ssl version:s3_clnt.c:851
```

...

```
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1.1
  Cipher    : 0000
```

But from **B** it works out of the box without any parameter.

```
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : AES128-SHA
```

The problem is that some library seems to use this setting and is not able to connect from A (works from B). So I think its the same reason - I am not able to pass some SSL-parameters to the library.

Does anyone knows if this behavior is configured or set somewhere?

Comment: Do both **A** and **B** use the exact same configuration for that POP3 server?

Comment: All important configuration is shown above. It is only host and port. The problem is the SSL, not the POP3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about trying solve a programming problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no global setting for ciphers or protocols which affect all OpenSSL based applications on the system. My guess is that the difference is in the network, like

- there is a SSL intercepting middlebox (firewall or similar) somewhere
- the target is different, i.e. A and B use different IP addresses for connecting to the server. This might be because the server is reachable by IPv4 and IPv6 but one system has IPv6 connectivity while the other does not. But there are also other reasons why different IP addresses might be used.

Comment: A and B are differently connected to the internet. After inspecting the SSL I can see a handful of certificates in the handshake. The 1st from A differs to the 1st of B. The rest is equal.

So how exactly can this interfer my connection-request and how can I handle it?

Comment: @chris: Different certificates might be caused by SSL interception but also by use of different target IP with a different configuration of the servers. Could you publish more details about the differences, like a packet capture for both connections (at cloudshark.org) or the certificates itself?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for your advise. The firewall was inspecting. After disabling it it was running well.

Comment: @chris: it is interesting that the firewall had problems with the default SSL handshake done by s_client. Could you say what kind of product this firewall was?

Comment: Sure! It is a Fortinet gateway. For more information I need to ask the network guy. He disabled the SSL-inspection and afterwards it worked as expected. 

Thanks again for your help! It cost me half a day of cracy trying and I am sure I still would without your comment.